# C preprocessor: declare structure data from a given enum value

Tags: c, enums, preprocessor

I am trying to automatically declare a given data structure from an enum value. A simple example is worth thousand words:

```
#define X_FIELDS \
    X(A, upd_foo) \
    X(B, upd_bar)

enum MSGS_TYPES {
#define X(msg_type, data_type) msg_type,
    X_FIELDS
#undef X
    MSGS_SIZE
};

#define DECLARE_MSG(name, type)           X(type) name = { type };  

typedef struct {
    enum MSGS_TYPES type;
    int x;
} upd_foo;

typedef struct {
    enum MSGS_TYPES type;
    int y;
} upd_bar;

int main() {
    DECLARE_MSG(msg, B);     
    printf("%d\n", msg.type);
    msg.y = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I'd like for DECLARE_MSG macro to declare
`upd_bar msg = { B };`
Is there any way to achieve that?

Note that I already tried something like:

```
#define T_A    upd_foo
#define T_B    upd_bar

#define _T(type)  T_type
#define X(type)   _T(type)
#define DECLARE_MSG(name, type)           X(type) name = { type };
```

But it obviously isn't working, complaining that ‘T_type’ is an unknown type name.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There's no obvious reason why you need an X macro to declare the variable here, since X macros should be used for repetitive tasks, not for declaring one single item. Simply write `upd_bar msg = { B };` without the macro. 

If you want variables of a certain struct type to always be pre-initialized to a certain enum value, create a default initializer list per struct type.

Comment: Yes, I was just toying with that.   

> "If you want variables of a certain struct type to always be pre-initialized to a certain enum value, create a default initializer list per struct type."

This is exactly what I was trying to avoid though. Thanks anyway! I think there is no way to achieve that.

Comment: Well, you _could_ probably make an ugly macro such as `#define DECLARE(name, type) type name = _Generic(*(type){0}, upd_foo: foo_list, upd_bar: bar_list)` that expands to a type-specific initializer list... but that's really the last resort. It is better to try to solve the actual root cause _why_ you would need such evil macros.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I did not think about that.  
In the end, i just  settled around a "typedef struct { enum MSGS_TYPES type; union { upd_foo foo; upd_bar bar; }; } message_t;"  this way i could easily DECLARE_MSG(type) as message_t { type }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T_type` is considered single token, and `type` argument is not found on macro expansion.

You need to use concatenation operator `##`:

```
#define _T(type)  T_##type
```

Comment: Wow how stupid i am! Thanks.   
Is there any method using an X macro, just like i tried above, to avoid declaring T_A, T_B ecc ecc for any enum value?

Comment: @Federico There may be, but I cannot think of how from top of my head right now. Messing with preprocessor always requires some extra thought. Since it's a separate issue, you are better of asking new question.

Comment: Indeed that was the main question (this is the reasong X_FIELDS was declared that way); i think it is strictly related though.

Comment: @Federico as you have accepted the answer, chances are slim that someone else will look into this question, much less the comments, so user694733 is right, put this in another question.